# WPF DataGrid header with CheckBox checked all the CheckBoxes in the DataGrid

Tags: wpf, linq-to-sql

in a WPF Project i have a DataGrid with severals columns and a last one with a checkbox in the header and for checkbox for every rows two.:

```html
 <DataGrid x:Name="CommDataGrid"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding id}"/>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ENTREE">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding dateEntree,StringFormat='dd/MM/yyyy'}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ARTICLE" Binding="{Binding article}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="N° PALETTE" Binding="{Binding numPal}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ADRESSE" Binding="{Binding picking}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="PBRUT" Binding="{Binding SumPdsBrut}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="POIDS NET" Binding="{Binding SumPdsNet}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="LOT" Binding="{Binding MinLot}"/>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="DATE CONGELATION">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding MinDatecong,StringFormat='dd/MM/yyyy'}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="DLUO">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding MinDLUO,StringFormat='dd/MM/yyyy'}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="Test">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                            <CheckBox x:Name="SelectAll_Ckb" Checked="SelectAll_Ckb_Checked"
                                      Unchecked="SelectAll_Ckb_Unchecked"/>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox x:Name="ChoixPalette_Ckb" Checked="ChoixPalette_Ckb_Checked"
                                          CommandParameter="{Binding Path= id}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

this DataGrid is implemented by a LinqToSql Query :

```
 private void ValidChoixBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ValidChoixBtn.Cursor = Cursors.Wait;
        using(BdCretsDataContext dc=new BdCretsDataContext())
        {
            #region Requete
            var article = from ent in dc.STOCK_ENT
                          join art in dc.FICHES_ARTICLES on ent.ART_CODE equals art.ART_CODE
                          join det in dc.STOCK_DET on ent.ENT_ID equals det.ENT_ID
                          where !ent.ENT_NUM_PAL.Contains("FDR_") && ent.ENT_OUTDATE == null
                          && ent.ART_CODE == (string)ProduitCB.SelectedValue
                          && ent.ENT_PICKING != null && ent.ENT_PRECO == 0
                          group new { ent, art, det } by new
                          {
                              ent.ENT_ID,
                              ent.ENT_DATE_ENT,
                              art.ART_CODE,
                              art.ART_LIBELLE1,
                              ent.ENT_NUM_PAL,
                              ent.ENT_PICKING
                          } into grouped
                          select new
                          {
                              id = grouped.Key.ENT_ID,
                              dateEntree = grouped.Key.ENT_DATE_ENT,
                              artCode = grouped.Key.ART_CODE,
                              article = grouped.Key.ART_LIBELLE1,
                              numPal = grouped.Key.ENT_NUM_PAL,
                              picking = grouped.Key.ENT_PICKING,
                              SumPdsBrut = grouped.Sum(x => x.det.DET_PBRUT),
                              SumPdsNet = grouped.Sum(x => x.det.DET_PNET),
                              MinLot = grouped.Min(x => x.det.DET_LOT),
                              MinDatecong = grouped.Min(x => x.det.DET_DATE_CONG),
                              MinDLUO = grouped.Min(x => x.det.DET_DLUO)
                          };
            #endregion

            #region Creation et Implementation du DataGrid
            dt = new DataTable();
            DataColumn dt1 = dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
            DataColumn dt2 = dt.Columns.Add("dateEntree", typeof(DateTime));
            DataColumn dt3 = dt.Columns.Add("artCode", typeof(string));
            DataColumn dt4 = dt.Columns.Add("article", typeof(string));
            DataColumn dt5 = dt.Columns.Add("numPal", typeof(string));
            DataColumn dt6 = dt.Columns.Add("picking", typeof(string));
            DataColumn dt7 = dt.Columns.Add("SumPdsBrut", typeof(float));
            DataColumn dt8 = dt.Columns.Add("SumPdsNet", typeof(float));
            DataColumn dt9 = dt.Columns.Add("MinLot", typeof(string));
            DataColumn dt10 = dt.Columns.Add("MinDatecong", typeof(DateTime));
            DataColumn dt11 = dt.Columns.Add("MinDLUO", typeof(DateTime));
            DataRow dw;
            foreach (var c in article)
            {
                dw = dt.NewRow();
                dw["id"] = c.id;
                dw["dateEntree"] = c.dateEntree;
                dw["artCode"] = c.artCode;
                dw["article"] = c.article;
                dw["numPal"] = c.numPal;
                dw["picking"] = c.picking;
                dw["SumPdsBrut"] = c.SumPdsBrut;
                dw["SumPdsNet"] = c.SumPdsNet;
                dw["MinLot"] = c.MinLot;
                dw["MinDatecong"] = c.MinDatecong;
                dw["MinDLUO"] = c.MinDLUO;
                dt.Rows.Add(dw);
            }
            CommDataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
            #endregion

    }
```

[image: IMG]

What i'm trying to achieve is : when the user checks the checkBox in the last column header, it checks all the checkboxes in the Datagrid.
Thank you for your help.
Can this be done easily in my situation ??

Comment: Updated the answer. I forget to format the code snippet how to use it, so it was not visible the whole time. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `MultiBinding` on the column cell's `CheckBox'.

Add a `DependencyProperty` to the Window or hosting `Control` of the `DataGrid`:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsSelectAllRecordsEnabledProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
  "IsSelectAllRecordsEnabled",
  typeof(bool),
  typeof(MainWindow),
  new PropertyMetadata(default(bool)));

public bool IsSelectAllRecordsEnabled { get { return (bool) GetValue(MainWindow.IsSelectAllRecordsEnabledProperty); } set { SetValue(MainWindow.IsSelectAllRecordsEnabledProperty, value); } }
```

Then create a multi value converter:

```
class SelectAllMultiValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
  // Column header CheckBox changed flag
  private bool isSelectAllChanged = true;

  // Index Values
  // 0:Column header CheckBox 1:Row cell CheckBox 2:SomeItemDataModel
  public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    object result = this.isSelectAllChanged ? values[0] : values[1];
    if (this.isSelectAllChanged)
    {
      // Update the data model (BindingMode.TwoWay)
      // when the value was triggered by the select all CheckBox
      (values[2] as SomeItemDataModel).IsSelected = (bool) result;
    }

    // Reset column header CheckBox changed flag
    this.isSelectAllChanged = true;
    return result;
  }

  public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    // Value is from the row cell CheckBox and not from the column header
    this.isSelectAllChanged = false; 

    // Column header select all CheckBox (index 0) must not change
    return new []{Binding.DoNothing, value};
  }

  #endregion
}
```

Add the converter instance to a `ResourcDictionary` within the scope of the `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
  <SelectAllMultiValueConverter x:Key="SelectAllMultiValueConverter" />
 </DataGrid.Resources>
```

Then bind the `CheckBox` of the header cell to the new `DependencyProeprty` and set the `MultiBinding` on the `CheckBox` of the cell:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="Test">
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
    <CheckBox x:Name="SelectAll_Ckb"
              IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:MainWindow}, Path=IsSelectAllRecordsEnabled, Mode=TwoWay}" />
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>

  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="SomeItemDataModel">
      <CheckBox x:Name="ChoixPalette_Ckb">
        <CheckBox.IsChecked>
          <MultiBinding UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" 
                        Mode="TwoWay"   
                        Converter="{StaticResource SelectAllMultiValueConverter}">
            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:MainWindow}"
                     Path="IsSelectAllRecordsEnabled" />
            <Binding Path="IsSelected" />
          </MultiBinding>
        </CheckBox.IsChecked>
      </CheckBox>
    </DataTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

This will do it. In your code the `CheckBox` of the row cells is not bound to anything. So the `CheckBox.IsChecked` will not be visible to your code. I set the binding source to `IsSelected`. You need to add this property to your data model (or some other boolean property). This is just to show how you you can link the `CheckBox` of the row cells to the header `CheckBox` while the row cell 
check boxes still work independently.

Comment: Just to be pedantic: `IsSelected` should be a property on the viewmodel that wraps the model (entity). If it's worth doing then it's worth doing properly; selection is a UI related activity, so don't pollute your models with it (I'm ignoring the fact that the OP's code is quite non-compliant with the MVVM pattern).

Comment: I agree. But when I say "data model" it's in the context of the UI (`CheckBox`). A wrapper that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. `IsSelected` is just the name to reflect the UI context. I don't know the context of this models. It could be a read-only flag, a high priority flag or any other meta data that is related to the business model. In most scenarios the binding source of a `CheckBox` is not UI related and maps directly to a value of a business entity.  If it is UI related (e.g. toggle background), the binding source of the `CheckBox` should be an Attached Property (e.g of a row).

Comment: If I had more context, I would have given it a better and more descriptive name.

Comment: Thank you for this code. I only have one problem, with this piece of code : (values[2] as SomeItemDataModel).IsSelected = (bool)result;I don't know what to write to remplace "SomeItemDataModel" ??